# ERROR : 'EBADMSG' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, sql, database, sqlplus

I am trying to connect C++ with SQL Plus database. In Code::Blocks, it throws an error when running:

```
ERROR : 'EBADMSG' was not declared in this scope.
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    MYSQL* conn;
    conn = mysql_init(0);
    conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "", "MaBD", 0, NULL, 0);
    if (conn)
    {
    }

    else
    {
        cout <<" Connection failure"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Change `stdio.h` to `cstdio` in C++.

Comment: Random guess: try moving `#include <errno.h>` before `#include <mysql.h>`

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: `MYSQL* conn;
    conn = mysql_init(0);` --> `auto* conn = mysql_init(nullptr);` - Won't fix the problem, but much nicer and more in line with modern C++.

Comment: See also [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) and [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)